# AccessControlException when check write folder permission

Tags: java, access-control

I would like to check write permission on folder. Folder may be user.home or something else. Whatever folder I put to the FilePermission, I catch this..

Some code:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission(System.getProperty("user.home"), "write"));
    System.out.println("tadam");
}
```

}

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\AntonovDI" "write")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
at ru.inversion.jinved.impl.Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

Why?

I know another solution, but I'm still interested in =)

```
      Path userHomePath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")).toAbsolutePath();
        if (Files.isWritable(userHomePath)) {
            System.out.println("tadam");
        }
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what your user.home-Folder looks like (or what permissions it has set etc.), but I would strongly recommend to put put your code into a try-catch-statement, to make sure that it doesn't stall whenever an AccessControlException is thrown; since it inherits from RuntimeException it is an unchecked exception, thus you won't get an compiler error.

Comment: Thanks...I just tried to simplify code, you see. I know about it and write permission is exist well. User home is C:\Users\AntonovDI, as you can see it in stacktrace. And I noted that it doesn't matter what folder in argument. Something about policy of security in javadoc, but I don't know what is it exactly.

Comment: @Christian Exceptions don't 'stall' programs.

Comment: So please enlight a non-native what the correct verb is :-) If you don't catch an unchecked exception it will make the JVM terminate the program execution. That's what I meant when I said "stall".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions are not equivalent. The first one checks whether the Java sandbox grants write access to the file. As you don't appear to be using a security manager, it's pointless. The second one checks whether the operating system grants access. Not the same thing.